# Rails ActiveRecord time between 10:00 - 00:00

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

rails 4.2.3 with PostgreSQL.

DB table `company` has fields:

`start_day_time: string`
`end_day_time: string`

that store hours:minutes like:

start_day_time: 10:00, end_day_time: 23:00

ActiveRecord where expressions with comparison by this fields works well. I can find currently open company easily

```
today_date = Time.zone.now
today_date_time = today_date.strftime('%H:%M')
Company.where(
'start_day_time < ? AND end_day_time > ?', today_date_time, today_date_time
)
```

**The problem**

But comparison fail when `end_day_time` is 00:00. It works only if i use 23:59.

Is there are way to fix this? 
Can i use additional rule in my sql expression to turn 00:00 to 23:59 temporary only for this query?

The simplest way – do not store 00:00 in this fields. But they used in user interface to present company work hours.

Answer (score 1):

I just recently did something like this.
In my model I created a method called happening_now?

This is what it looks like

```
  def happening_now?
    Time.now.strftime('2000-01-01 %H:%m:%S').between?(self.starts_st, self.ends_at)
  end
```

I hope that this helps.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but this is not the my case. I need **where** query in activerecord to filter records in specific date range. What your solution does is just local date comparing and not applicable to sql.